# Disable extended tracking for image targets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

since Vuforia 7.2  Extended Tracking is automatically enabled for all targets when the Positional Device Tracker is enabled. Now i work on a app which uses ground plane features and image markers. I just want to use extended tracking for the ground plane, is there a way to disable them for the targets?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can disable it for a specific target. It can either be disabled for all or enabled for all. I would suggest using options when you want to track images and when you want to track ground planes, so that you can use call the below two functions when you want to enable or disable.

```
void StartExtendedTracking()
{
  PositionalDeviceTracker extendedTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<PositionalDeviceTracker>();        
  if( extendedTracker != null && extendedTracker.IsActive )         
  {
        extendedTracker.Start();         
  }
}

void StopExtendedTracking()
{
  PositionalDeviceTracker extendedTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<PositionalDeviceTracker>();        
  if( extendedTracker != null && extendedTracker.IsActive )         
  {
        extendedTracker.Start();         
  }
}

//If you want to disable/enable tracking completely then call the below functions

void StopTracking()
{
 TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Stop();
}

void StartTracking()
{
 TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<ObjectTracker>().Start();
}
```